# How to convert ueyesrc buffer to opengl texture?

Tags: opengl, gstreamer-1.0, wayland, google-coral, usb-camera

I'm trying to make a [UI-3370CP-C-HQ R2 Camera](https://en.ids-imaging.com/store/ui-3370cp-rev-2.html) work on a [Coral DevBoard](https://coral.withgoogle.com/docs/dev-board/datasheet/) with gstreamer.

Since the camera is no standard v4l2 camera, I downloaded and compiled the `ueyesrc` gst plugin (https://github.com/atdgroup/gst-plugin-ueye) on the devboard.

In my application I need to have the frame as opengl textures and I'm stuck at building a working pipeline.

So far the only way I managed to get something from the camera is to save a frame as jpeg:

`gst-launch-1.0 tee ueyesrc num-buffers=10 ! jpegenc ! filesinklocation=ueyesrc-frame.jpg`

The pipeline example provided with ueyesrc `gst-launch-1.0 ueyesrc ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink` doesn't work in my case because there is no X-Server on the device (but Wayland)

`gst-launch-1.0 ueyesrc ! videoconvert  ! glimagesink` returns the following error:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Got context from element 'sink': gst.gl.GLDisplay=context, gst.gl.GLDisplay=(GstGLDisplay)"\(GstGLDisplayWayland\)\ gldisplaywayland0";
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstGLImageSinkBin:glimagesinkbin0/GstGLImageSink:sink: Failed to convert multiview video buffer
Additional debug info:
gstglimagesink.c(1741): gst_glimage_sink_prepare (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstGLImageSinkBin:glimagesinkbin0/GstGLImageSink:sink
Execution ended after 0:00:00.486558117
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

With a standard USB webcam (Logitech HD Pro Webcam C920), `gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! videoconvert ! glimagesink` works fine.

I don't really understand what is going wrong or how to find more clues about it, I suppose I'm missing a conversion step in the middle but I don't know how to fix it. Does someone have an idea?

**edit 1**: it is indeed a conversion issue. I got it to work by specifying the format in the `videoconvert` caps: `gst-launch-1.0 ueyesrc exposure=2 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=YUY2 ! glimagesink sync=False`
Although the CPU usage is super high (>90% on all 4 cores of the iMx8) and the framerate reach a max of 6.5 fps.

Comment: Can you share the output of "v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext --device /dev/video1
" ?

Comment: `sudo v4l2-ctl --list-formats-ext --device /dev/ueye/130__2-1__3370
VIDIOC_QUERYCAP: failed: Inappropriate ioctl for device
/dev/ueye/130__2-1__3370: not a v4l2 node`